# Do all incorrect reviews trigger a suspension?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-suspension

I just received this message:

> You reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14287926
>   incorrectly. Please pay more attention to each review in future
>
> Come back in 5 days to continue reviewing

I looked into my review history and see that 3 other reviewers approved it, and one rejected it.

In retrospect, the description was wordy, but just curious since I have over 1000 reviews I want to learn.

How was it decided that the review was incorrect?
Was the single reviewer rejecting it enough to create the suspension, or as the review-suspension tag says was I ", manually banned by a ♦ moderator because of severe misuse of the reviewing system."?

Where would I have found this information on my own?

Comment: This has been a manual ban by a ♦ moderator. The only way to get banned automatically is to fail an audit, and tag wiki (excerpt) edits do not appear as edits.

Comment: Oh, and it's an incorrect review because it has been copied *verbatim* from [here](http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net).

Comment: @Glorfindel As a part of the review process, are we really supposed to check if something is plagiarized? Everything I've seen on Meta has always been to review a post on its own merits independent of even other answers. In that specific case, I agree with OP that on its own, it is just wordy

Comment: I'd love to hear the reasoning from the moderator. I think it's pretty crazy to expect reviewers to google for plagiarized content on every review.

Comment: Am I just wrong about that? Should that be expected behavior when reviewing?

Comment: If the reviewer doesn't check for that, who else is going to?

Comment: @Michael but who checks plagiarism in plain answers then?

Comment: @IanS Also reviewers? Checking for plagiarism in one queue doesn't preclude checking for it in another queue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It was an incorrect review because it was plagiarized from other sources without attribution, just like the reject reason stated. Being with the majority does not a correct review make.

And yes, you were manually banned by a moderator. I can tell because:

- The ban length was exactly 5 days.
- When you are automatically review-banned, it has this message:

  > You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see <link to the last audit you failed>.

---

> Where would I have found this information on my own?

In the reject reasons. One must pay attention to such things, because they do in fact vary between reviews.

Comment: "The ban length was exactly 5 days." I don't think so. Most likely the OP has been banned 2 days ago.

Comment: Note that detecting such plagiarization is pretty easy: [just use an internet search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22A+componentized+pattern+is+in+essence+a+context-independent%2C+reusable+and+type-safe+variation+of+the+original+pattern+that+covers+at+least+as+many+use-cases%22&atb=v40-6b_&ia=qa).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker sure it's easy once, but the question is: should it be done systematically at each review?

Comment: @IanS actually the question is why it was incorrect, how they were banned, and how it could have been found otherwise.

Comment: @IanS That's what I do...